# A question on Liouville number

Tags: liouville-numbers

The definition of Liouville number $l$ is, for every positive integer $n$, there exist integers $p,q$, such that
$$\left\vert l-\frac{p}q\right\vert<\frac1{q^n}$$ is satisfied.

However, in [an accepted and upvoted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654687/limit-of-left-sinn-right1-n) on MSE, it seems that one can choose $p,q$ arbitrarily. So, the definition of Liouville number should have *’for any’* replacing *’there exist’*.

What confused me more is that the Liouville approximation theorem states that:

For any algebraic number $x$ of degree $n>2$, a rational approximation $\frac{p}q$ to $x$ must satisfy
 $$\left\vert x-\frac{p}q\right\vert >\frac1{q^n} $$

This makes me guess that the inequality for Liouville numbers is satisfied for any $(p,q)$.

Which is correct and which is wrong?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Obviously there are rational numbers $\frac pq$ which are very far from $l$.

Comment: @lulu So $(p,q)$ is up to our choice?

Comment: Not following. Please write a complete sentence.

Comment: Your Liouville approximation theorem shows that an (irrational) algebraic number is **not** a Liouville number.

Comment: @lulu when we know a number is Louiville, is the first inequality true for any (p,q), if we know some bounds of distance between p and q?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but that's not complete.  What bounds is it that you know?

Comment: @lulu More directly, do you think the answer I quoted is correct?

Comment: The answer you quoted doesn't appear to say anything like what you said.  The definition of a Liousville number is not ambiguous.  $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ is a Liouville number iff for every positive integer $n$ there exists integers $p,q$ with $q>1$  and $0<|\alpha -\frac pq|< \frac 1{q^n}$

Comment: @lulu i am particularly uncomfortable with the fourth paragraph ‘Now choose p=n...’ How come one can choose p, q arbitrarily?

Comment: Write to the author and ask them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first definition you gave is correct.
I recommend you re-read what you linked. He said that pi is not a liouville number. The negation of there exists is for all.

Comment: Wow! That’s right! How come I missed that!