# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\cos (nx)|^{\frac{1}{n} }= 1$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory

don't know how to proceed with this. 
my thought: if there exist some $n_0, k_0 \in \mathbb{Z}, x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $n_0 x_0= \frac{\pi}{2}+k_0\pi $, then there exist countable sequence $\{(n_i,k_i)\}$ such that $n_i x_0= \frac{\pi}{2}+k_i\pi $, so the limit doesn't exist at $x_0$

Comment: What does $\left[\cos(nx)\right]^{1/n}$ mean whenever $\cos(nx)<0$ and $n$ is even ?

Comment: @Adren sorry I forgot to add the absolute value sign. edited

Comment: Does $x$ really have a bearing on this problem?

Comment: See the related [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1654687/505767).

Answer (score 4):

Let $U\in[0,2\pi)$ be uniformly random. Since $\cos$ has bounded derivative, there exists a constant $C$ such that for every $\delta>0$,
$$
\mathbb P(|\cos U|<\delta)<C\delta.
$$
Since $nU$ mod $2\pi$ is also uniformly random for all $n\geq 1$, this implies
$$
\mathbb P(|\cos nU|<\delta)<C\delta,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\mathbb P(|\cos nU|^{1/n}<\delta)<C\delta^n.
$$
Since for all $\delta<1$ the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C\delta^n$ is finite, it follows by the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Statement_of_lemma_for_probability_spaces) that there are almost surely only finitely many $n$ such that $|\cos nU|^{1/n}<\delta$, and hence that
$$
\liminf_{n\geq 1}|\cos nU|^{1/n}\geq \delta\quad \text{almost surely},
$$
for all $\delta<1$. Taking a sequence of $\delta$'s tending to $1$ shows that the liminf is at least $1$ almost surely. But since $|\cos nU|^{1/n}\leq 1$, we get a matching upper bound, showing that the limit exists (almost surely) and equals $1$ (almost surely), as desired.

Comment: @gimusi and others in this thread, I believe my answer deserves more visibility, and in particular the "drive-by downvote" should be counteracted.